# casts property is not working to change date format

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-models

I am trying to change date format while fetching data in this way

```
 protected $casts = [
        'due_date' =>  'date:d-m-Y',
     
    ];
```

Blade

```
{{$ticket->due_date}}
```

It is showing is like

```
2022-03-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casts are for json serialization (`json_encode($ticket)`). To get the format you want in blade, use `Carbon`'s `format` method.

```xml
{{ $ticket->due_date->format('d-m-Y') }}
```